# Another class within the Navigation Properties not getting mapped : AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I am trying to map using AutoMapper classes which have navigation properties(EmployeeLeave) which has an instance of another class(Leave). I was able to map the navigation property but not the class within the navigation property

```
namespace Project.Core.Entities
{
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
          [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required, MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot exceed 50 characters")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public EmployeePersonalDetails EmployeePersonalDetails { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeLeave> EmployeeLeaves { get; set; }
      }
}
```

The second class is

```
namespace Project.Application.Models
{
 public class ApplicationUserModel 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required, MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot exceed 50 characters")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


         public EmployeePersonalDetailsModel EmployeePersonalDetailsModel { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeLeaveModel> EmployeeLeavesModel{ get; set;}
     }
}
```

There is another class(Leave) which is an instance in the EmployeeLeave class

```
namespace Project.Core.Entities
{
   public class EmployeeLeave : Entity
    {
        public ApplicationUser Employee { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Leave Leave { get; set; }
        public int LeaveId { get; set; }
        public string LeaveStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is mapped with

```
namespace Project.Application.Models
{
   public class EmployeeLeaveModel : BaseModel
    {
        public ApplicationUserModel Employee { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public LeaveModel LeaveModel { get; set; }
        public int LeaveId { get; set; }
        public string LeaveStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is how I am mapping classes

```
namespace Project.Application.Mapper
{
   public class EmployeeProfile : Profile
    {
        public EmployeeProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Leave, LeaveModel>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<ApplicationUserModel, ApplicationUser>().ReverseMap()
                .ForMember(a =>a.EmployeeLeavesModel , b =>b.MapFrom( b => b.EmployeeLeaves));
            CreateMap<EmployeePersonalDetails, EmployeePersonalDetailsModel>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<EmployeeLeave, EmployeeLeaveModel>().ReverseMap();
           

        }
    }
}
```

This is the method for calculating annual leave taken by the employee where 2 classes are getting mapped

```
 public async Task<double> TotalAnnualLeaveTaken(int userId)
        {
            var employee = await _employeeLeaveRepository.GetEmployee(userId);

            var user = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUserModel>(employee);
    ///rest of the method

        }
```

In the TotalAnnualLeavetaken() method , the employee is getting it value from ApplicationUser class through _employeeLeaveRepository and the navigation property EmployeeLeaves is mapped using 'for member()'. I want the Leave of the EmployeeLeave class to also map with the LeaveModel of the EmployeeLeaveModel   . Is there a way to map it?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when you use `AssertConfigurationIsValid()`?

Comment: No I did not get any such exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping from `EmployeeLeave` to `EmployeeLeaveModel` does not know what to do with the properties `EmployeeLeave.Leave` and `EmployeeLeaveModel.LeaveModel`. You have to tell him like this:

```
CreateMap<EmployeeLeave, EmployeeLeaveModel>()
    .ForMember(it => it.LeaveModel, it => it.MapFrom(it2 => it2.Leave));
```